# Is Hyper-V CSVFS supported on Linux VMs

Tags: linux, failovercluster, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, cluster-shared-volumes

We have a Hyper-V guest failover cluster with a few Windows VMs that are using Cluster Share Volume (CSV).

Is it possible to use the same CSV for Linux VMs? Is CSVFS supported on Linux VMs at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux has its own clustered file systems.  If you want to share a disk among Linux machines, you need to form a cluster of those Linux machines and run a clustered file system on them.  CSVFS is a Windows technology.

You'd still probably be happier with a file server.

Comment: Yes it seems that would be the case. We have setup everything and whole csvfs over svhdx is just one complexity over another. We will try file server in the end. Thanks